# IPsec tunnel won't stay up

Tags: vpn, ipsec, juniper, strongswan, srx

I have a static IPsec tunnel configured between a Debian cloud server running StrongSwan and a Juniper SRX 210. The tunnel goes up just fine, but it never stays up for long, the longest may be about 1hr. I think it's because there isn't much data traversing the tunnel and it times out.

StrongSwan config:

```
# ipsec.conf - strongSwan IPsec configuration file

config setup

# Add connections here.
conn vpn.mydomain.com
    auto=start
    keyexchange=ikev2
    authby=secret
    ike=aes128-sha256-modp2048s256
    ikelifetime=3h
    esp=aes128-sha256
    left=AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD
    leftid=@reverser.mydomain.com
    leftsubnet=192.168.2.0/24
    leftsourceip=192.168.2.2
    right=vpn.mydomain.com
    rightid=@vpn.mydomain.com
    rightsubnet=192.168.1.0/24
    dpdaction=hold
    dpddelay=60
    dpdtimeout=500
```

SRX Config (partial):

```
proposal ike-vpn-proposal {
    authentication-method pre-shared-keys;
    dh-group group24;
    authentication-algorithm sha-256;
    encryption-algorithm aes-128-cbc;
}
policy ike-vpn-policy {
    mode aggressive;
    proposals ike-vpn-proposal;
    pre-shared-key ascii-text "SECRET"; ## SECRET-DATA    }
gateway vpn-local-gw {
    ike-policy ike-vpn-policy;
    address AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD;
    dead-peer-detection {
        interval 10;
        threshold 3;
    }
    local-identity hostname vpn.mydomain.com;
    remote-identity hostname reverser.mydomain.com;
    external-interface fe-0/0/7.0;
    version v2-only;
}


proposal ipsec-vpn-proposal {
    protocol esp;
    authentication-algorithm hmac-sha-256-128;
    encryption-algorithm aes-128-cbc;
}
policy ipsec-vpn-policy {
    perfect-forward-secrecy {
        keys group24;
    }
    proposals ipsec-vpn-proposal;
}
vpn vpn {
    bind-interface st0.0;
    ike {
        gateway vpn-local-gw;
        proxy-identity {
            local 192.168.1.0/24;
            remote 192.168.2.0/24;
        }
        ipsec-policy ipsec-vpn-policy;
    }
    establish-tunnels immediately;
}


security-zone trust {
    host-inbound-traffic {
        system-services {
            all;
        }
        protocols {
            all;
        }
    }
    interfaces {
        vlan.100;
    }
}
security-zone untrust {
    screen untrust-screen;
    interfaces {
        fe-0/0/7.0 {
            host-inbound-traffic {
                system-services {
                    dhcp;
                    ike;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
security-zone vpn {
    interfaces {
        st0.0;
    }
}
```

SRX IKE and IPsec status:

```
root@dravis> show security ike security-associations
Index   State  Initiator cookie  Responder cookie  Mode           Remote Address
1402228 UP     3551524e1af4a5e3  9dbc38ed8519f12b  IKEv2          AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD

root@dravis> show security ipsec security-associations
  Total active tunnels: 0

root@dravis> show security ipsec inactive-tunnels
  Total inactive tunnels: 1
  Total inactive tunnels with establish immediately: 1
  ID     Port  Nego#  Fail#  Flag      Gateway          Tunnel Down Reason
  131073 500   8      0      600a29    AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD  Delete payload received
```

StrongSwan Status:

```
Status of IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.2.1, Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64, x86_64):
  uptime: 92 days, since Aug 24 17:41:13 2016
  malloc: sbrk 1495040, mmap 0, used 312800, free 1182240
  worker threads: 11 of 16 idle, 5/0/0/0 working, job queue: 0/0/0/0, scheduled: 2
  loaded plugins: charon aes rc2 sha1 sha2 md5 random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem openssl fips-prf gmp agent xcbc hmac gcm attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default stroke updown
Listening IP addresses:
  AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD
  10.10.0.5
  192.168.2.2
Connections:
vpn.mydomain.com:  AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD...vpn.mydomain.com  IKEv2
vpn.mydomain.com:   local:  [reverser.mydomain.com] uses pre-shared key authentication
vpn.mydomain.com:   remote: [vpn.mydomain.com] uses pre-shared key authentication
vpn.mydomain.com:   child:  192.168.2.0/24 === 192.168.1.0/24 TUNNEL
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
vpn.mydomain.com[941]: ESTABLISHED 2 hours ago, AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD[reverser.mydomain.com]...EEE.FFF.GGG.HHH[vpn.mydomain.com]
vpn.mydomain.com[941]: IKEv2 SPIs: e3a5f41a4e525135_i 2bf11985ed38bc9d_r*, pre-shared key reauthentication in 15 minutes
vpn.mydomain.com[941]: IKE proposal: AES_CBC_128/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_256/MODP_2048_256
```

Comment: Strongswan 5.2.1 ( <5.3.0 ) with ikev2 doesn't support the new setting charon.make_before_break and can only do break before make when reauthenticating. Maybe check that the Juniper isn't doing the opposite and is considering the "Delete Payload" as final?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I resolved the issue by setting explicit re-keying intervals at both sides - 3hrs for IKE, 12hrs for IPsec.

I do not know why this solved it, which worries me, but the tunnel has remained up for several days with no problems.